# local and remote configuration of a virtual com port

Tags: command-line, usb, powershell, batch, com-port

I am trying to reconfigure a known (virtual?) com port on multiple computers on a local network using a batch file.

A USB device we use is installed always as com9 and always comes in as 9600 baud default, and we have to manually reconfigure each station to 57600 baud.

I already have this batch file renaming printers, dns servers, Killing and starting tasks, copying files and a whole lot more, I've experimented with mode, but I'm either not using it properly or it can't do what I want.

I know I can use the GUI, but for the sake of speed, I want the batch to do it.

Sorry if this is a copy, but I'm seeing if anyone has an angle for me, I'm not afraid of personal research, but I'm running into dead ends with no leads.

Ask if you need any clarifications, and thanks in advance.

Powershell is okay too if I know what I need and can still stay in the cmd environment.